# Groovy inject without a similar Java 8 reduce

Tags: groovy, java-8

Normally I think of Groovy's `inject` method as equivalent to Java 8's `reduce`, but I seem to have hit an unusual situation.

Say I have a POJO (or POGO) called `Book`

```
class Book {
    int id
    String name
}
```

If I have a collection of books and want to convert them to a map where the keys are the ids and the values are the books, then in Groovy it's easy enough to write:

```
Map bookMap = books.inject([:]) { map, b ->
    map[b.id] = b
    map
}
```

i.e., for each book, add it to the map under the book's id and return the map.

In Java 8, the same operation would take a completely different approach. Either this:

```
Map<Integer, Book> bookMap = books.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Book::getId, b -> b));
```

or, equivalently,

```
bookMap = books.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Book::getId, Function.identity()));
```

the difference being a matter of style.

What I'm wondering, however, is if there is a `reduce` operation in Java 8 that would be similar to the `inject` from Groovy. I can't just mimic what I did in Groovy, because in Java 8 the signature for `reduce` is:

```
T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)
```

The `BinaryOperator` means that both elements of the lambda expression must be of the same type. If it was a `BiFunction`, I could make the lambda's first argument a `HashMap<Integer, Book>` and the second argument a `Book`, but I can't do that with a `BinaryOperator`. I know there's a three-argument version of `reduce`, but that doesn't seem to help either.

Am I missing something obvious? Is it just that `inject` is more general that `reduce`? Since I already have an idiomatic way of solving the problem in Java, this isn't critical, but I was struck by the differences here.

Answer (score 3):

Yo Ken! :-D

You need the [3 parameter form of `reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), so given:

```
List<Book> books = Arrays.asList(
        new Book(1, "Book One"),
        new Book(2, "Tim's memoirs"),
        new Book(3, "Harry Potter and the sarcastic cat")
);
```

You can do:

```
Map<Integer, Book> reduce = books.stream().reduce(
        new HashMap<Integer, Book>(),
        (map, value) -> {
            map.put(value.id, value);
            return map;
        },
        (a, b) -> {
            a.putAll(b);
            return a;
        }
);
```

To give:

```
{
    1=Book{id=1, name='Book One'},
    2=Book{id=2, name='Tim's memoirs'},
    3=Book{id=3, name='Harry Potter and the sarcastic cat'}
}
```

The first parameter is the thing to collect into:

```
        new HashMap<Integer, Book>(),
```

The second parameter is a BiFunction that takes the current accumulator, and the next element in the stream, and combines them somehow:

```
        (map, value) -> {
            map.put(value.id, value);
            return map;
        },
```

The third binary operator in that reduce call:

```
        (a, b) -> {
            a.putAll(b);
            return a;
        }
```

Is how to join all the resulting maps back together assuming you are running a parallel stream...

`put` and `putAll` returning `void` make it a fugly mess :-(  But I guess chaining wasn't a popular thing back in the late 90s...

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. I'm still puzzling over why the reduce method was designed that way (with a separate accumulator and combiner), while inject in Groovy (as usual) is so much easier, but so be it.

Also, I assume that the sarcastic cat in "HP and the Sarcastic Cat" is probably McGonagal in animorph form.

Comment: The combiner is only used in the case of `parallel()` streams...  If you put `throw new RuntimeException("boom")` in the combiner, you'll see for normal streams it doesn't get called...